# Computation in javascript using times

Tags: javascript

How to use times in javascript? Formula is `5+1000/1000+20000/10000+3000/10000*0.06 = 0.66` in calculator 5+1+2+3*0.6=0.66. I don't know if some of my computation is wrong or the code is wrong.

I try to search it but still same result, yet on calculator is different.

```js
function calc() {


  var today = new Date();
  var month = today.getMonth(); // Returns 9
  month = month + 1;
  console.log(month); // Output: 9


  var textValue3 = document.getElementById('input3').value;
  var textValue2 = document.getElementById('input2').value
  var textValue1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  var basic = 5;
  var rate_interest;
  if (month == 1) {
    rate_interest = 0;
  } else if (month == 2) {
    rate_interest = 0;
  } else if (month == 3) {
    rate_interest = 0.06;
  } else if (month == 4) {
    rate_interest = 0.08;
  } else if (month == 5) {
    rate_interest = 0.10;
  } else if (month == 6) {
    rate_interest = 0.12;
  } else if (month == 7) {
    rate_interest = 0.14;
  } else if (month == 8) {
    rate_interest = 0.16;
  } else if (month == 9) {
    rate_interest = 0.18;
  } else if (month == 10) {
    rate_interest = 0.20;
  } else if (month == 11) {
    rate_interest = 0.22;
  } else if (month == 12) {
    rate_interest = 0.24;
  }
  document.getElementById('output').value = (basic) + (textValue1 / 1000) + (textValue2 / 1000) + (textValue3 / 1000) * (rate_interest);
}
```

Comment: I'm finding your question a bit confusing. How does the formula relate to your code snippet? Your snippet does not seem to give the error you're describing, so it's difficult to know what your error is.

One potential cause for the error is that the `value` returned by the inputs are always going to be strings, not numbers. Try surrounding that expression with `parseFloat` or `parseInt`

P.S. Unrelated help, you may wish to simplify your if/else block to `if (month < 3) rate_interest = 0; else rate_interest = month * 0.02`

Comment: the computation bro i dont know how to get 5+1000/1000+20000/10000+3000/10000*0.06 = 0.66 in calculator 5+1+2+3*.06= 0.66

Comment: Lets walk through this and see where differences may arise. Here's the equation copied from your question: 5+1000/1000+20000/10000+3000/10000*0.06 - Hmm, a bit nasty to look at, lets add some parenthesis 5+(1000/1000)+(20000/10000)+(3000/10000*0.06) Now lets sum the terms.. 5 + 1 + 2 + (0.3 * 0.06) ---> 8 + 0.018 - You're mistaken. 3000/10000 is not 3, it's 0.3

Comment: Also, PLEASE, investigate the `switch` reserved word. That great big "else if _____" block will dissolve into something much more readable.

Comment: Yes but the 3 is from input 3 can be change 1 4 etc because invert 1000 value /1000 so i get 1 in every 1000 value

Comment: `5+1000/1000+20000/10000+3000/10000*0.06 = 0.66` What? Please open console, paste: `5+1000/1000+20000/10000+3000/10000*0.06` and hit Enter. What result do you get?

Comment: Also, you say that the formula (which is completely wrong BTW) is `5+1000/1000+20000/10000+3000/10000*0.06` but than you're doing: `(basic) + (textValue1 / 1000) + (textValue2 / 1000) + (textValue3 / 1000) * (rate_interest)` which is NOT your formula at all. See the `10000`?? `10000` is not `1000`... now I'm wondering about that `20000`...

Comment: Also... `5+1+2+3*0.6` gives `9.8`, not `0.06`... Math

Comment: And if you really use a calculator, and if you enter in this sequence: 5+1+2+3*0.6 - will give you `6.6`, not `0.06` . And that's because `11 * 0.6` *is* `6.6`

Comment: Also, PS: your 25 lines of if/else can be condensed into one line: `rate_interest = month < 3 ? 0 : month * 0.02;` Simple math with a Ternary Operator...

Comment: Also `3000/10000` is not `3` - it's 0.3....

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is completely broken.

- An Input value will always be a **String**! It's your job as a developer to transform it into a Number using  [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or  [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).
- Remember:

  - On a calculator, if you do **1 + 2 * 5** ...if you take a close look it's a **resolved sequence**. Therefore `1 + 2` results in **3** and thenafter `3 * 5` results in **15**.
  - On any better calculator you can also write compound expressions and also use **Brackets** `(`  `)`
  - In math, (therefore also in programming), if you do `1 + 2 * 5` it's just like writing this expression:  `1 + (2 * 5)` results in **11** - due to **Operator Precedence**.

```js
const
  EL_in1 = document.querySelector('#input1'),
  EL_in2 = document.querySelector('#input2'),
  EL_in3 = document.querySelector('#input3'),
  EL_int = document.querySelector('#interests'), 
  EL_out = document.querySelector('#output');

const calc = () => {
  const
    basic = 5,
    month = new Date().getMonth() + 1,
    v1 = parseFloat(EL_in1.value),
    v2 = parseFloat(EL_in2.value),
    v3 = parseFloat(EL_in3.value),
    rIt = (month < 3 ? 0 : month * 0.02).toFixed(2),
    out = (basic + v1 / 1000 + v2 / 1000 + v3 / 1000) * rIt;
  EL_int.value = rIt;
  EL_out.value = out.toFixed(2);
}

[EL_in1, EL_in2, EL_in3].forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("input", calc));
calc();
```

```css
[type=number] {width: 45px;}
```

```html
(
  5 +
  (<input id="input1" type="number" value="1000"> / 1000) + 
  (<input id="input2" type="number" value="2000"> / 1000) +
  (<input id="input3" type="number" value="3000"> / 1000) 
) *
<input id="interests" type="number" readonly> = 
<input id="output" type="number" readonly>
```